# Problems with using PHP to display CSV file as HTML table

Tags: php, html, csv

I'm trying to display a two column, four row CSV file in an HTML table. I have the code below, but it only displays the first row and I don't understand why.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border=1>
        <?PHP
        $file_handle = fopen("oee1.csv", "r");
        while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
            $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
            echo '<tr><td>' . $line_of_text[0] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[1] . '</td></tr>';
        }  
        fclose($file_handle);
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The csv file looks like:

```
test1, 1
test2, 2
test3, 3
test4, 4
```

Comment: I don't know the exact answer, but I do know that the example on [fgetcsv](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) doesn't use feof at all, but just checks the return value of `fgetcsv` itself.

Comment: change fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);  to fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024,",");

Comment: that hasn't fixed the problem I'm afraid!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were not iterating through every line.
Try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>+test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if (($file_handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== false) {
                $str = '';
                $str .= '<table>';
                while (($data = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024, ",")) !== false) {
                    $str .= '<tr>';
                    foreach ($data as $key => &$value) {
                        $str .= "<td>$value</td>";
                    }
                    $str .= '</tr>';
                }
                fclose($file_handle);
                $str .= '</table>';
                echo $str;
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

output:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>test1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test2</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test3</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test4</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

PS: make sure you have priviledges and your csv is in the smae directory as your php file.

Reference : [fgetcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it (although I may be putting the code in the wrong place or not closing brackets properly - I'll keep trying!)

Comment: can you provide any sample data?

Comment: question updated with example of csv file (not using real data for now)

Comment: For some reason this gives me all my data in one row. I think it must be to do with the way new lines are marked in my csv file but I don't really understand why!

Comment: in this case use ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE); read about it on the link i provided

Comment: That's solved it! Serves me right for trying to test files built on RPi on a macbook!

Answer (score 0):

try adding a call to `fgets($file_handle);` in each iteration of the loop, you have to advance the file handle pointer somehow.

Comment: sorry, could you elaborate what you mean by this please?